# UISlider Animation using MMSegmentSlider

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uislider

I have found an amazing UISlider library but i want to know if I can put images in those circles or just images in their place.

[image: Here is the image]

[Link to the library MMSegmentSlider](https://github.com/MedvedevMax/MMSegmentSlider)

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to change the blue images

Comment: Yes. In spite of this blue dots I want to put images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the property from **MMSegmentSlider**

[image]

**use like for change the color**

```
self.segmentSlider.selectedValueColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "red.png")!)
```

Comment: Thank you very much